# Can I use "although... + main clause + so/but..." construction?

Tags: grammar

For example

> Although he has eaten a big steak, he is stilling eating, so he must
> be extreme hungry.

and

> Although he has eaten a big steak, he is stilling eating, but I have
> no more food for him.

The matter is, both *although* and *so/but* are conjunctions and are exclusive for each other, but what if I put a main clause between them?

Comment: No; only "but" is a conjunction. In modern grammar, "although" and "so" are prepositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem using both **although** and **so** in the same sentence. Your examples are both possible although most native English speakers would insert **already**:

> Although he has already eaten a big steak, he is still eating, so he must be extremely hungry.**

(Note: **extremely** not **extreme**.)

This construction is common in English:

> Although it's raining, we have to attend the meeting, so we had better leave now.

I can't think offhand of a typical example using **although** followed by **but**.

Others may well be able to.